Obtaining a non-bijective linear map from two isomorphisms on a vector space
In the question here, it's shown that any non-bijective linear map $\phi:V\to V$ can be written as the difference between two bijections when $V$ is finite dimensional. I am wondering when/how we can get the reverse implication as well, but I am having trouble reversing the construction.
Specifically, I'm wondering if given two isomorphisms $f,g$ there is a non-trivial linear combination $af+bg$ that is not bijective. I am just thinking about the cases when $V$ is finite dimensional and $F=\mathbb{C}$ or $F=\mathbb{R}$.
If $F=\mathbb{C}$, say we have two isomorphisms $f,g:V\to V$. If there is $v\ne0$ so that $af(v)=bg(v)$ for some nonzero $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, then the function $af-bg$ has non-trivial kernel and we're done. In particular, over $\mathbb{C}$ we know $f$ and $g$ must have eigenvectors (since $V$ is finite dimensional), so if $f$ and $g$ share an eigenvector then we're done by the above argument. But in the case that they do not share an eigenvector I am struggling to reverse the construction in the linked question.
In the case of $F=\mathbb{R}$, I suspect it shouldn't be true because some operators might not have eigenvalues, but I can't seem to find a real vector space $V$ and two isomorphisms $f,g$ so that any non-trivial linear combination is an isomorphism (where $f$ and $g$ are not scalar multiples of each other).
If anyone knows the argument for such results I would greatly appreciate it.

Consider the matrices
$$
M = \pmatrix{0 & 1\\ -1 & 0}\\
K = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 1}
$$
each of which defines an isomorphism of the plane by left multiplication (i.e., $v \to Mv$).
If $aM + bK$ were singular, then we'd also have $M + \frac{b}{a}K$ singular, so we can just look at
$$
M + rK = \pmatrix{r & 1 \\ -1 & r}
$$
whose determinant is $r^2 + 1 \ne 0$ for any $r$. So no nontrivial linear combination of these two isomorphisms ever fails to be an isomorphism.
Pro tip: Try 4 examples before ever trying to prove anything.  (I was told that Euler liked to try dozens, and who better to emulate?)

This is only for the case $F=\mathbb{R}$ though, right? Because over $\mathbb{C}$ we can have $r=i$ give a singular matrix

That's right. But you wanted to know if the conjecture was true in general, so a single counterexample suffices. I'll bet that with a little effort, you could use this example to create a $4 \times 4$ example that fails over $\mathbb C$. I'm pretty sure that I could, but that's because I practice that whole "build examples before proving" skill. You might even be able to find an $8 \times 8$ example that fails over the quaternions, although maybe commutativity would get in the way there.

Actually, I lied. The characteristic polynomial of $M + rK$ is ... a polynomial with complex coefficients, and it's nonconstant unless $K = 0$. Such a polynomial has a root over $\mathbb C$, so there's an $r$ such that $M +rK$ is singular (i.e.,not an isomorphism).

I'm struggling to relate the second sentence. I've been able to reduce $\det(M+rK)=\frac{1}{\det(M^{-1})}\det(I+rM^{-1}K)$ so that if $c$ is an eigenvalue of $M+rK$ it must divide $\det(I+rM^{-1}K)$, but I'm not sure this helps. I can't seem to relate the char. poly. of $M+rK$ having a root to giving us the value of $r$ we desire (which i suspect has to do with an eigenvalue of $M$)

If $s$ is that root, then the determinant of $A = 1M + sK$ is zero. Having a zero determinant means that $0$ is an eigenvalue, i.e., that the kernel of $A$ is nontrivial -- it contains some nonzero vector $v$. And that, in turn, means that $u \to Au$ cannot be an isomorphism, because both $A0 = 0$ and $Av = 0$, so $0$ and $v$ map to the same item; the map isn't even an isomorphism on the set level!

Thank you for your help, that first sentence is the part I am currently struggling with. If $s$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $M+rK$,, then $\det(sI-(M+rK))=0$. How can we obtain that $\det(M+sK)=0?$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Take $V = \Bbb{R}^2$, and let $f$ be the identity on $V$ and let $g$ be anticlockwise rotation through $90^o$. With respect to the standard co-ordinate system we can write;
$$
f = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \quad \quad g = \pmatrix {0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0}
$$
Then for any $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$, we have the following formula for the determinant of $af + bg$:
$$
|af + bg| = \left|\begin{array}{cc}a & -b \\ b & a\end{array}\right| = a^2 + b^2
$$
If $af + bg$ were not bijective, this determinant would be $0$, but $a^2 + b^2 = 0$ implies $a = b = 0$.

I think you were looking over my shoulder as I worked, Rob. :)

@JohnHughes: no, I just type slower than you do $\ddot{\smile}$. The OP is right to comment that we've only answered one of his or her two questions in one.

Yep. And now I see that you didn't copy: your rotation is in the other direction. :) I did advise OP to consider how to generalize this example to a 4x4 example for complexes.
